# Finding a basis for a fairly unique set

Tags: linear-algebra

$B = \{(1+y,2-2y,3+3y)\ $|$ $t $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$$\}$

Where vector addition and scalar multiplication are defined by:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1+y_1\\ 
2-2y_1\\ 
3+3y_1
\end{pmatrix}$
$\oplus 
\ \begin{pmatrix}
1+y_2\\ 
2-2y_2\\ 
3+3y_2
\end{pmatrix}$ =  $\begin{pmatrix}
1+y_1 + y_2\\ 
2-2y_1 - 2y_2\\ 
3+3y_1 + 3y_2
\end{pmatrix}$

$k \odot \begin{pmatrix}
1+y_1\\ 
2-2y_1\\ 
3+3y_1
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}
1+ky_1\\ 
2-2ky_1\\ 
3+3ky_1
\end{pmatrix} $

My answer:

At first I wanted to say that the basis can be defined by $\{(1,0,3),(0,2,0)\}$ but when I go to show linear independence i.e

$k1\odot$$V1\oplus k2\odot V2 = \{(1,2,3)^T\}$

it gets messy and it comes out as a linearly dependent set. Where am I going wrong here? I choose the two vectors as the third element in the vector is a linear combination of the first. Is V one-dimensional as opposed to two-dimensional as I assumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the vectors in $V$ only depend on one parameter should indicate to you that $V$ is one dimensional.  In fact, I can define $W=\{u,-2u,3u)|u \in \Bbb R\}$ with usual addition and multiplication, which is clearly one dimensional. Then there is an isomorphism $(t+1,2-2t,3+3t)\in V \leftrightarrow (t,-2t,3t)\in W$

Comment: Bear with this, this is my first course in liner algebra.


For defining a basis, do I choose a random parameter of t? My problem is, if I choose t=0, then I get the vector (1,2,3), which is the zero vector, however if I recall correctly, for a a single vector set to be a basis then it cannot contain the identity vector as then it wouldn't be linearly independent, is this right?

Do I get around this by just picking a different value for t, say t=1?

Comment: Yes, you can pick any $t$ other than $0$.  Similarly, in $W$ you can pick any $u$ other than $0$.  You are correct that the zero vector cannot be part of a basis.  For a one dimensional subspace, any other vector than the zero vector is a basis.